# How do I validate a sendTransaction value?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, metamask

On my e-commerce website, I would like to add ETH payment through metamask. I have the basic logic to send a transaction (see below) and it works fine.

However, when the metamask window pop-ups, I am able to edit the transaction and change the transaction value (ex: from 0.1 to 0.0000000001). I have a feeling this is not the correct way to accept payments since I am unable to confirm the transaction value.

How should I accept ETH payments? This is what I have so far:

```
const trans = await web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: address,
    to: 'xxx',
    value: web3.utils.toWei('0.1', "ether"),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best way to do this but I was able to compare the sendTransaction value with the returned transaction.

```
const confirm = await web3.eth.getTransaction(trans.transactionHash);
console.log(web3.utils.fromWei(confirm.value, "ether"));
```